# Can someone Vectorize the diffusion() function

Tags: vectorization

I am unable to vectorize this code

the Given Information to do is 
vectorizing diffusion()

The diffusion workload has a true vector dependency over timesteps, so this workload can not be vectorized over timesteps. One solution to this issue is to implement loop-interchange to make the particle loop to the inner loop.

In order to implement the interchange, you must create a temporary buffer to store the positions of the particles. Furthermore, the random number generator can't be in the vectorized loop. So you must generate and store multiple random numbers before the vectorized loop. You can generate n_particles random numbers with:

```
float rn[n_particles];
vsRngUniform(VSL_RNG_METHOD_UNIFORM_STD,
             rnStream, n_particles, rn, -1.0, 1.0);
```

The given Code to vectorize is

```
int diffusion(
     const int n_particles,     // num of particles
     const int n_steps,         // num of timesteps
     const float x_threshold,   // x cutoff
     const float alpha,         // for dist_func
     VSLStreamStatePtr rnStream // RNG
    ) {
  int n_escaped=0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n_particles; i++) {
    float x = 0.0f;
    for (int j = 0; j < n_steps; j++) {
      float rn;
      // Intel(R) MKL RNG
      vsRngUniform(VSL_RNG_METHOD_UNIFORM_STD,
                   rnStream, 1, &rn, -1.0, 1.0);
      x += dist_func(alpha, rn); 
    }
    if (x > x_threshold) n_escaped++;
  }
  return n_escaped; 
}
```

Comment: What is `dist_func` and what have you tried yourself so far? (The wording of your question sounds a bit like you copied a homework question ...)

Comment: @chtz yes it is an assignment question and I am not able to complete it after many tries

Comment: @chtz link to download the question files and  my best solution  https://drive.google.com/file/d/17bZskmjFmPw6Hzf3z23SN0RbMQ7FFsw8/view?usp=sharing